# How to file upload using ajax jquery in mvc for IE9 only

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to use this below code in IE9(IE9 only)
Please help

```
var formData= new FormData();
var imagefile=document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
var coverfile=document.getElementById("coverFile").files[0];
formData.append("imageFile",imageFile);
formData.append("coverFile",coverFile);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/Profile/EditProfile", true);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) { UploadComplete(evt); }, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) { UploadFailed(evt); }, false);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax
This guy has a pretty good method?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your script in conditional commands like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script>
var formData= new FormData();
var imagefile=document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
var coverfile=document.getElementById("coverFile").files[0];
formData.append("imageFile",imageFile);
formData.append("coverFile",coverFile);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/Profile/EditProfile", true);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) { UploadComplete(evt); }, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) { UploadFailed(evt); }, false);
xhr.send(formData);
</script>
<![endif]-->
```